# Trying to hide excess info on a running balance

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok, it has been a while since I did spreadsheets. I have the running balance working great, all the information is spot on. However, when I try to extend the formula it shows the balance all the way down, instead of just showing on lines that have the information in it. So if using =SUM($D$2:E2) formula how does the IFBLANK work into that to keep F column empty until values are plugged into D and E.

Thank you to everyone that did respond. I just don't know enough to understand what you are asking me to do. I'm sorry if I offended anyone or wasted your time. I put the formula that's being used in the original question, and stated that I tried to make the ifblank work. Also, I explained the function needed. I appreciate the help, but I'll probably just give it up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may want to upload a screencap to http://imgur.com and link to it. Someone with enough reputation will likely embed it for you

Comment: Ok so how to clarify? I have an account spreadsheet where column D is expenses, column E is income made, and column F is a running balance. The question is, how do I keep the balance in F to stay blank until I enter the credits and debits in D and E. I have tried the ifblank but I don't understand how to make it work within the formula

Comment: Share the formula you have so far and the things you've tried, share a mockup of the data. These are things that should be added to the question.

Comment: And please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1835138/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: This is what you need to do: `=IF(AND(D2="",E2=""),"",N(F1)+E2-D2)` Where `Column D` refers to `Expense Column` and `Column E` refers to `Income Column` while `Column F` is the `Running Balance` Column in cell `F2` enter the formula. Also there is no `IFBLANK()` function in excel, but there is `ISBLANK()`

Comment: You could also just use a **Table**. When you enter a formula in the first row it will extend down the column. And will extend to new rows as you add them.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, then you could use the following formula, commented above as well, showing a demo as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=IF(AND(D2="",E2=""),"",N(F1)+E2-D2)
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down and fill it down as far you need. However, if using `MS365` then one could try this as well, but I prefer the above which is simple to use.

```
=IFNA(TAKE(SCAN(0,E2:E100-D2:D100,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="","",a+v))),
 MATCH(2,1/(MMULT(N(D2:E100<>""),{1;1})))),"")
```

---

Also, one better option is to use the following formula, if it may happen, you have deleted any rows then the simple formula will return `#REF!` error, but the second formula won't return any error and it will certainly work irrespective of any.

However, if you are reluctant to use formula with `LAMBDA()` helper functions then use the following, which needs to fill down, as far you need, this can also be achieved using `OFFSET()` function, but avoided using it since its `VOLATILE` in nature, which means if there is any change in any open workbook then the formulas will recalculate, as well it slows down the working functionalities of Excel:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=IF(AND(E2="",D2=""),"",
 SUM(E$2:INDEX(E:E,ROWS(F$2:F2)+1)-
 D$2:INDEX(D:D,ROWS(F$2:F2)+1)))
```

---

Or this:

```
=IF(AND(E2="",D2=""),"", SUM(E$2:E2-D$2:D2))
```

---